# Create Collection in Azure Search Service Using View

Tags: azure, sql-view, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to create index which using import data tool.

The datasource is from azure sql's view.

```
SELECT
b.Name,
b.ID
(SELECT
'[' + STUFF((
    SELECT
        ',{"name":"' + p.Name + '"}'
    FROM Product p WHERE p.Brand = b.ID
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE)
.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') + ']') AS TAry, 
b.IsDelete,
b.ModifyDatetime
from Brand b
```

Column with TAry will return JSon format string like:
[{"name":"Test1"},{"name":"Test2"}]

In Indexder properties with field TAry Chose the type Collection(Edm.String)

After create , It's return error , the message below:

"The data field 'TAry' has an invalid value. The expected type was 'Collection(Edm.String)'."

Thank for your reply.

I have try this kind format :[Test1","Test2"] still not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to use Azure Search REST API to set up a field mapping with jsonArrayToStringCollection function. Take a look at [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-indexers-customization/#transform-strings-from-a-database-table-into-string-collections) for detailed instructions.

Comment: Also, format of the string must be an array of string literals: ["red", "blue", "green"]

Comment: Firs at all thanks for the answer.
I have try this solution. and the index build scuess.
But , i get some question.
1. If i set the field TAry as EDM.String , is the mapping with mappingFunction still work?
2.set up the field mapping is the last action to finish this? 
3.if the Collection(Edm.String) colud be searchable?

Comment: 1. jsonArrayToStringCollection produces a string collection, so its target field must be a string collection. 2. Should be 3. Yes